# React's setState method with prevState argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, just have a question on setState method. Let's say we have a component:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    count: 3
  };

  Increment = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      options: prevState.count + 1)
    }));
  }
}
```

so why we have to use `prevState` in the `setState` method? why can't we just do:

```
this.setState(() => ({
  options: this.state.count + 1)
}));
```

Comment: Try invoking your setState command multiple times and see the results for yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Functional setState (previous state) different from new updated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203864/react-functional-setstate-previous-state-different-from-new-updated-value)

Comment: "React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state."

Comment: *Usually* this doesn't matter as React will always batch multiple `setStates` triggered from the same event listener. That said, it is always a good idea to use the callback approach whenever you want to set a new state that depends on the old state.

Comment: You want to avoid mutating state. Best practice is to create a new array using prevState as a starting point and return that.

Comment: @clint_milner neither approach mutates the state directly. Both are fine, the one could just be considered a "better practice" than the other.

Answer (score 53):

Both signatures can be used, the only difference is that if you need to change your state based on the previous state you should use `this.setState(function)` which will provide you a snapshot(`prevState`) from the previous state. But if the change does not rely on any other previous value, then a shorter version is recommended `this.setState({prop: newValue})`

```
this.setState(prevState =>{
   return{
        ...prevState,
        counter : prevState.counter + 1
   }
})

this.setState({counter : 2})
```

Comment: Don't do `prevState.counter++` as this mutates `prevState`. Do `prevState.counter + 1` instead.

Comment: It does. From the docs `The first argument is an updater function with the signature: (state, props) => stateChange. state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated`. Besides why would you want to update `prevState.counter` and the return object counter when you only want to increment the latter? You could in theory also have another key that relied on `prevState.counter` which would not work if you did `++`. Say, `someCountDown: prevState.counter - 1`.

Comment: I'm just saying it is a bad practice. I have done this exact mistake myself in the past and have had issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: So does this mean that if we give a function as the argument for setState, then setState will automatically supply this function with the current state as a parameter?

Answer (score 26):

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  Increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
  };

  IncrementWithoutPrevState = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(() => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(() => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }));
    this.setState(() => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.IncrementWithoutPrevState}>
          Increment 4 times without PrevState
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.Increment}>
          Increment 4 times with PrevState
        </button>
        <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just made an example for you to give an idea what is meant by "React may batch multiple setState()..." and why we should use prevState in the above scenario.

***First, try to guess*** what should the result of `Count` when you click both buttons... If you think the `count` will be incremented by 4 on click of both buttons then it's not right guess ;)

***Why? because*** in `IncrementWithoutPrevState` method since there are multiple `setState` calls, so React batched all those calls and updates the `state` only in the last call of `setState` in this method, so at the time of last call to `setState` in this method `this.state.count` is not yet updated and its value is still the same that was before entering into `IncrementWithoutPrevState` method so the resultant state will contain `count` incremented by 1.

***Now on the other hand side if we analyze the `Increment` method:***
Again there are multiple `setState` calls and React batched them all that means the actual state will be updated in the last call of `setState` but the `prevState` will always contain the modified `state` in the recent `setState` call. As `previousState.count` value has already been incremented 3 times till the last call of `setState` so the resultant `state` will contain the count value incremented by 4.

Answer (score 4):

If you call a function multiple times to change the value of a state property in a single `render()` function call then the updated value will not go over between the different calls without prevState mechanism.

```
second(){
   this.setState({ // no previous or latest old state passed 
       sec:this.state.sec + 1
     }, ()=>{
        console.log("Callback value", this.state.sec)
   })    
}

fiveSecJump(){ // all this 5 call will call together  
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
   }

  render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div>  Count - {this.state.sec}</div>
              <button onClick ={()=>this.fiveSecJump()}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Finally sec value will be 1, because calls are async, not like  high-level programming language like c++/c# or java where there is always a main function which maintains the main thread.
Therefore if you want to have `fiveSecJump()` function to work properly you have to help it by passing it an arrow function. prevState. prevState is not a keyword or member function, you can write any word here like oldState, stackTopState, lastState. It will convert to a generic function which will do your desired work.

```
class Counter extends Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sec:0
        }
   }
   second(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            sec:prevState.sec + 1
        }))
   }

   fiveSecJump(){
       this.second() // this call found sec = 0 then it will update sec = 0 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 1 then it will update sec = 1 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 2 then it will update sec = 2 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 3 then it will update sec = 3 +1
       this.second() // this call found sec = 4 then it will update sec = 4 +1

   }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div>  Count - {this.state.sec}</div>
              <button onClick ={()=>this.fiveSecJump()}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter
```

Answer (score 2):

here iseveryone know just state:prevstate.counter+1.. we can also do this with state:this.state.counter+1.  This is not the way i think to use prevstate. i have problem in array when i push into existing state it allow me but second time it prevent changes

Answer (score 1):

@samee's answer was great and helped me out. I wanted to revive this topic to address React Function Components simply because that is what I'm currently studying.

The following is an example of why **you might want to use prevState if the new state is computed using the previous state**.

```
function App() {
  const [developer, setDeveloper] = useState({
    yearsExp: 0,
  });

  function handleYearsExp() {
    setDeveloper((prevState) => ({
      yearsExp: prevState.yearsExp + 1, //increments by 1
    }));
    setDeveloper((prevState) => ({
      yearsExp: prevState.yearsExp + 1, //increments by another 1
    }));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleYearsExp}>Increment Years</button> {/* will increment by 2 */}
      <p>
        I am learning ReactJS and I have {developer.yearsExp} years experience
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's the code without the `prevState` function passed into `setState`. Notice that the first `setState` function is essentially ignored.

```
function App() {
  const [developer, setDeveloper] = useState({
    yearsExp: 0,
  });

  function handleYearsExp() {
    setDeveloper({
      yearsExp: developer.yearsExp + 1, // is ignored
    });
    setDeveloper({
      yearsExp: developer.yearsExp + 1, //increments by 1
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleYearsExp}>Increment Years</button> {/* will only increment by 1 */}
      <p>
        I am learning ReactJS and I have {developer.yearsExp} years experience
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

References:

1. [ReactJS.org - "Pass a function to setState"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)
2. [ReactJS.org - "React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a different type of real example as compared to other solutions above so you would know that why **prevState** is required in somecases. This code chunk is from my own project just for your understanding. **filteredProducts** is an array of products and each product has id , price, createdAt(date).

```
// you fetched your data with code below 
 const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(http://localhost:5000/api/productscategory)
            
        );
        setFilteredProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [cat]);

// now you made select html tag(with 3 values-(asc,desc,newest) for filters.
```

**and** want to sort your fetched data. For that you need to just play with previous state and sort it.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (sort === "newest") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
      );
    } else if (sort === "asc") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      );
    }
  }, [sort]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is the example to explain both concepts:


import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { counter: 0 }
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1})
    }

    increment3() {
        this.increment();
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
    }
   render() {
        return (
            <div>
               count-{this.state.counter}
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => this.increment3()}>Increment</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

In this scenario when we click on **Increment** button then the output will be rendered into the UI is **count-0** not **count-3** because react groups all the state call in a single state call and does not carry the updated value over every incremented call. If I want to update the value based on the previous value then use below mentioned code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { counter: 0 }
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState((prevState=>({counter:prevState.counter+1})))
    }

    incremental() {
        this.increment();
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
     
    }
   render() {
        return (
            <div>
               count-{this.state.counter}
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => this.incremental()}>Increment</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

In this scenario the output will be **count-3** not **count-0**

Answer (score 0):

I look about the question, and also on handling-events (react website). I come to idea to try this way, for me more natural, and they work.
I have confusion on about using .bind when this is undefined in callback. I'm correct write handleClick function?

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    // this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); - i Deleted this because we have arrow fun. down
  
  }

  handleClick = (this.setState) => {
      this.isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```