# Changing Parent State with Arrow Function Inside a Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Register User Function Which Looks Like this:

```js
  onRegisterUser = () => {
    const { email, password, isLoading} = this.state;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    registerUser(
      email,
      password,
      () =>
        this.setState({
          isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,
        }),
      navigation
    );
  };
```

The Function Receives the Input email, pass and isLoading state from the Register Screen and does the following:

```js
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import { newUser } from "./database";

export const registerUser = (email, password, toggleLoading) => {
  toggleLoading();

  const isInputBlank = !email || !password;
  if (isInputBlank) {
    Alert.alert("Enter details to signup!");
    toggleLoading();
  }
  //If Everything OK Register User
  else {
    //CR: change to async-await
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        newUser(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.

        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
          alert("The password is too weak.");
        } else if (errorCode == "auth/invalid-email") {
          alert("Email is Invalid");
        } else if (errorCode == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
          alert("Email is Already in use!");
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```

My problem is that the `toggleLoading();` Inside `if (isInputBlank)` doesn't do anything
I'm trying to change the isLoading state if I get an error (Empty Input in this Example) but it does nothing,
It works only one time in the start and that's it.
If the Alert is Activated when i close it the loading screen Remains

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your set loading function

```js
() =>
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
     isLoading: !prevState.isLoading
  })),
```

Comment: I think this post and article will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495198/reacts-setstate-method-with-prevstate-argument

Comment: https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60

Answer (score 1):

should it not be better to chain to the original promise like so:

```
 export const registerUser = (email, password) => {
  if (!email && ! password) { 
   return Promise.reject('Email and Password required'); // or whatever message you like to display
  }
  
  return (
    yourCallToFirebase()
     .then(() => newUser())
     .catch(() => {
       let errorMessage;
       // your error handling logic
       return Promise.reject(errorMessage);
     })
  )
 };
```

usage

```
onRegisterUser = () => {
 const { email, password, isLoading} = this.state;
 const { navigation } = this.props;
 this.setState({ isLoading: true })
 registerUser(email,password)
  .then(() => {
   // your logic when user gets authenticated (ex. navigate to a route)
  })
  .catch((errorMessage) => { 
   // display feedback (like a toast)
  })
  .finall(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
};
```

Comment: I still want to know why it doesn't work the way I did it

Comment: that might be due to the state being stale

Comment: check @WilTree answer