# REACT, Help me understand prevState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

What is the difference between defining this counterHandler like this

```
counterHandler = () => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return { times: this.state.times + 1 }
        });
    }
```

And this?

```
 counterHandler = () => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return { times: prevState.times + 1 }
            });
        }
```

Does the state from a component always gets passed to setState automatically?

Comment: I think this might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496277/8546128

Comment: `this.setState` sets values asynchronously, if `this.state.times` initialises as `1` and you call `this.setState(() =>{ return { times: this.state.times + 1 }; })` twice in the same handler the resulting value in `this.state.times` will be `2`. If you did the same with  `this.setState((currentState) =>{ return { times: currentState.times + 1 }; })` you would end up with `this.state.times` of `3`

Comment: Yes, if you pass a function to `setState`, the current state is passed to the function as an argument. Compare to `this.setState({ times: state.times + 1 })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use One data inside state, you dont need to make callback of prevState,
but if your state more than one, you need to callback of prevstate because this will make your other and previous data will not be lost.

for example

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
loading: false,
data: []
})

const handleLoading = () => {
setState({
loading: true
})
}

const handleData = () => {

setState({
data: [a,b,c] // you will lost your loading = true
})}

const handleData = () => {
setState((prevState) => {
...prevState,
data: [a,b,c] // you still have loading = true
})
}
```