# Filter todos by different criteria using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a todo list where i can change each todo by status with a dropdown.;

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const todos = [
    {
      title: 'test',
      id: 1,
      done: false
    },
    {
      title: 'test2',
      id: 2,
      done: true
    },
  ]
  const [myTodo, setMyTodo] = useState(todos);

  const changeStatus = (e, id) => {
      console.log(e.target.value, id)
      const newValues = todos.map(i => {
        if(id === i.id) {
          return {
            ...i,
            done: e.target.value === 'false' ? true : false
          }
        }
        return i;
      })
      setMyTodo(newValues);
  }

  const filterDone = () => {
      const r = myTodo.filter(i => i.done === true);
      setMyTodo(r)
  }

  const filterActive = () => {
    const r = myTodo.filter(i => i.done === false);
      setMyTodo(r)
  }

  const filterAll = () => {
      setMyTodo(myTodo)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
            <button onClick={filterAll}>Filter By all</button>
      <button onClick={filterDone}>Filter By donne</button>
      <button onClick={filterActive}>Filter By active</button>

      {
        myTodo.map(t => {
          return <div>{t.title} 
          <select onChange={(e) => changeStatus(e,t.id)} name="status">
          <option hidden>status</option>
          <option value='false'>Done</option>
          <option value='true'>Active</option>
         </select>
         {t.done ? 'done' : 'active'}
         </div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

There i want to filter the todos by status using these 3 button, but when i filter i don't get the expected result. If i click multiple times on different filter i don't get any results.

How to fix the code to be able to change the status of the item and also after that to be able to filter the list? How to solve? 
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-thunder-jywy6?file=/src/App.js:0-1506

Comment: @Dupocas, my question is not how to use `filter()`, but what is the issue in my code? Could you restore the question?

Comment: @edhi.uchiha, could you provide a link to codesanbox?

Comment: You are mutating the state `const r = myTodo.filter(i => i.done === false)` should be `setTodo(todo => todo.filter(...))`.Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495198/reacts-setstate-method-with-prevstate-argument/55496277#55496277

Comment: @edhi.uchiha I don’t see any common things with my question your answer. I didn’t find something related with filtering