# React.js understanding setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React.js and reading through react.js official docs. There is a example presented by the official docs, that I have questions for:

original code:

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

my question is :
in the handleClick method, why can't this.setState be written as(without the arrow function):

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    });
}
```

Comment: You can, as long as you use `isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn` (because right now you're pulling `prevState` out of thin air in your example, whereas in the page's example code, setState is called with a callable function, and that variable is function's argument, automatically filled in by React for you)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't do that is that `prevState` will be `undefined` and you can't access property key on the `undefined` object. Whenever you want to change logic based on your previous state you should be using callback function so you can avoid unnecessary direct mutations of state.

Answer (score 0):

In this case both will work. But sometimes you get unexpected output when changing the state on the previous state value. For more info go to
[React's setState method with prevState argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495198/reacts-setstate-method-with-prevstate-argument)

You can understand there.