# ReactJS Stop the counter at certain limit using for loop and eventHandling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, jsx

I have the following JSX code and I want to stop the counter once it reaches 51. The counter should start only once the event is triggered and it should make a continuous call until it reaches 51.

I tried using useEffect but it won't stop the counter.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    title: "Current count",
    count: 0
  });

  const stateUpdater = function () {
    // 101 iterations
    for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      // Only even numbers
      // There are a total of 51 even numbers in between 0 and 101
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        setInfo({ count: info.count + 1 });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{info.title}:</h2>

      {/* Count: This output should become 51 after clicking the button once */}
      <div>{info.count}</div>

      <button onClick={stateUpdater}>Run state updater</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. 
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the react docs:

> React may batch multiple setState() (in this case `set` method of
> useState) calls into a single update for performance. Because
> this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should
> not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument

The fix:

```
if (i % 2 === 0) {
   setInfo((prevState) => {
     return {
       count: prevState.count + 1
     };
   });
}
```

For more info go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55497074/9740537).