# when i fill a form input it shows the previous value in console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

when i fill a form input it shows me previous value e.g if i type 1 it shows "" and after that if i type 2 then it shows "1" and soo on like its showing the value of previous state. i cant figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated thanks

```
const Create = () => {

let history = useHistory();

let [person, setPerson] = useState({
    name:"",
    about:"",
    email:"",
    image:"",
})

let createPerson = async () => {
    fetch(`/api/person-create/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "content-type": 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(person)
    })
}

let handleChange = (e) => {
    setPerson({...person, [e.target.id]: e.target.value})
    console.log(person)
}

return (
    
    <form>
        <div>
            <h2 className="notes-title" style={{marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/')} className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
                    &#10094; Back
                </button>
            </h2>


            <h2 className="mt-4 mb-4" style={{width: '600px', marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                New Person
            </h2>

            <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px', marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value={person.name} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px', marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">About</label>
                <textarea style={{height: '250px'}} className="form-control" id="about" placeholder="Tell us somthing about yourself" value={person.about} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px', marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" value={person.email} />
            </div>

            <div className="custom-file mt-3" style={{marginLeft:'700px'}}>
                <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="image" value={person.image} />
                <label className="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit"  style={{marginLeft:'700px'}} className="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>

        </div>
    </form>

    )
}

export default Create
```

i get that its happening because the state only updates once i put somthing inside the form but cant figure out a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setPerson` asyncronous function, you must check person update in `useEffect`. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous)

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("correct", person);
  }, [person]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-smoke-riv3i)

Answer (score -1):

Better you use `Previous State` when you update your state. Please follow the below code:

```
let handleChange = (e) => {
    setPerson( (per) => ({...per, [e.target.id]: e.target.value}));
    console.log(person)
}
```

Comment: It's not work, `setPerson` asyncronous

Comment: I wrote my solution in comment under question and yes `setPerson` is https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203864/react-functional-setstate-previous-state-different-from-new-updated-value

Comment: I know this, but in this case `console.log(person)` after `setPerson` with your code will be show previous value as well

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-smoke-riv3i demo with your solution is not work as neeeded

Comment: oh man, you are update the person with my code and showing that using console in useEffect and you are saying that is not working :) useState will not show you updated state immediately you should know that. I expect anymore comment from you as I have not enough time to do that.

Comment: its not working for me khabir how will adding (per) will solve it tho

Comment: @Khabir, with @naveed `setPerson` work the same as with your code, you can test in my demo

Comment: @naved, you will get the update immediately instead you need to use useEffect with the dependency. Moreover you need to replace all `let` with `const`

Comment: Your code is correct, yes, but it not resolve @naveed question